# Axios error For Hosting React App On AWS S3

Tags: reactjs, typescript, csv, amazon-s3, axios

[Error Image is Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCHyM.png) My Site has one upload button where We can upload .csv File , Whenever We Upload the File it gets inserted in AWS S3 . But When it is hosted on S3 it gives error i.e unpromise of axios. But when I try to run in Localhost it works perfectly without any error , The error only happens when the file is uploaded from the hosted site of AWS S3 Bucket

I Tried Adding export {AxiosInstance} but it didnt Worked